# Stanford CoreNLP - Leematisation of Words

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to leematize a sentence using Stanford NLP, using the following code

```
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class Entry
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;
        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props, false);
        String text = "This is my text";
        Annotation document = pipeline.process(text);

        for(CoreMap sentence: document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class))
        {
            for(CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class))
            {
                String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
                String lemma = token.get(LemmaAnnotation.class);
                System.out.println("lemmatized version :" + lemma);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler is throwing me the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException : Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:558)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:267)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
at Entry.main(Entry.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by : edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException : Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:763)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:294)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:259)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:97)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:77)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:556)
... 9 more
Caused by : java.io.IOException : Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as either class path, filename or URL
at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:446)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:758)
... 14 more
```

I downloaded the jar files of the CoreNLP library and I'm using Idea IntelliJ.
Not being able to understand the error, Any idea anyone?

Comment: The file that is referenced by that IOException needs to be on the classpath or located relative to the application's working directory, so check that. It it is located inside a jar, make sure that jar is on the classpath. For setting the working directory when running inside Idea have a look at their documentation.

Comment: Your other option is to put the tagger file on a server and call it over http

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing the *models.jar. Unless memory is a major concern, I've found that compiling the full corenlp package into a single jar (models included) is the easiest way to deploy StanfordNLP.

The foolproof way is to clone the git repo and build the jar:

```
git clone https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP.git
cd CoreNLP
ant jar
```

Then, anytime you compile and run make sure you include the resulting jar:

```
javac -cp /path/to/javanlp-core.jar my.java
```

EDIT: It occurs to me that the *easiest* way is likely to build with maven and include Stanford NLP as a dependency, but if you're looking for a lighter weight option, then this works.